# if( fn1(args) || fn2(args){ "Add the elements into the list" ;}

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a doubt of how this if loop is going to work. if fn1 evaluates to be true, will it still go for checking fn2 or will it go into the if loop and add the elements into the list?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please search before posting, use appropriate tags, and ensure that your question really reflects the code you're askign about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `||` operator is *short-circuited*, meaning that if the left-hand operand is true (whatever that means in the language in question), the right-hand operator isn't evaluated at all. So in your example, `fn1` will definitely be called, but `fn2` will only be called if `fn1` returns `false`.

Comment: Yeah, I meant a function call with arguments(Edited my question). Thanks for answering